# Loading greyscale images in wxPython

Tags: python, image, wxpython

I'm writing a little desktop app using wxPython that does a bit of image manipulation, but I'm finding it's running rather slowly.

One of the biggest problems at the moment is that I am using three channels of data (RGB) where I only really need one - greyscale images are fine for my purposes.

At the moment I'm manipulating the images by loading them into a numpy array. Once the processing is done, they're converted into a wx Image object (via the `ImageFromBuffer()` function, which is then loaded into a `StaticBitmap` for the user interface. This seems like a lot of steps...

So I have two questions - the first is how would you load a numpy array directly into a greyscale wx Image? Is this even possible?

The second is more general - what is the fastest way of dealing with images in wxPython? I don't have much choice but to loop over the numpy arrays (I need the mathematical functionality), but any way of speeding things up before and after this process would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

you could do a pingpong with PIL like this :)

```
def convertToGrayscale(img): 
     import Image, ImageOps 
     orig = Image.new("RGB", img.GetSize()) 
     orig.fromstring(img.GetData()) 
     pil = ImageOps.grayscale(pil) 
     ret = wx.EmptyImage(pil.size[0], pil.size[1]) 
     ret.SetData(pil.convert('RGB').tostring()) 
     return ret
```

refer this link [link](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Images-colors-to-grayscale-conversion-td2313023.html)